# Best Voxel Engine/Language?

Tags: game-engine, minecraft, voxel

I'm researching making a voxel-based game similar to Minecraft, only this would be with slightly higher polygon voxels with higher texture resolutions in order to create smoother, more realistic terrain and also unique features like custom voxel-based characters, players, and enemies.

My question is what is the best engine and language to develop this type of indie game with that would be the most graphically optimized for this type of voxels?

Answer (score 0):

There is two types of awnser :
1- you are willing to put a lot of time and effort in your project and doing all layers of your game, therefor I would tell you to go with C++ and OpenGL/Vulkan (those are APIs to talk with GPUs at different levels of abstraction, OpenGL is more abstracted and does a lot of boring stuff for you but you have more control with Vulkan on your memory management/usage.

2- you want to try to make a game and you don't want to bother learning deep C++ and GPU logic and I would go for Unity or Unreal Engine.

Answer (score -2):

C++ is the language. Now the question remains is if you want to speed up rendering with the help of the gpu-s? If you want then you must either use OpenGL or Direct3D.
 I'm curious if OpenCL could enable a more complex voxel calculation by gaining more access to gpu hardware than OpenGL.